# Should a lockfree queue use a condition variable?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Suppose I have a lockfree queue in a multithreaded setting. I already provide a `try_dequeue()` method which allows for an optional failure (communicated via the return type) if the queue is empty.

I've found it convenient to have an always-succeeding `T dequeue()` method which will not return while the queue is empty. As a consumer, I don't really care when I get my product, I just want to know as soon as one's available.

My implementation of `dequeue()` is pretty simple:

```
while (true) {
    if (try_dequeue succeeded) return result;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx_);
    cond_.wait(lk, [this]{ return !empty(); });
}
```

Where `cond_` is signalled by enqueuers and `mtx_` guards `cond_`.

The excess serialization and between-dequeuer contention caused by `lk` seems to slow things down. `empty()` certainly doesn't need anything to be locked.

In any case, does `cond_` seem out of place here? The only reason I'm hesitant to remove it is the case where there's a dequeuer (or multiple dequeuers) that are waiting for a new item to come in and are spinning idly on the CPU with no indication for the enqueuing thread to get priority.

It would seem that perhaps `this_thread::yield()` is more appropriate here, but the standard only guarantees that the method is a hint, so there is a possibility of starving here.

It appears that [boost::lockfree::queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) does not provide a `dequeue`-like method at all. Hopefully the nuclear option is avoidable.

As user rwong points out, we may consider a solution to this problem as a "hybrid" or "semi-blocking" approach because it would be desirable to have dequeuers block on empty queues, yet it would also be nice for enqueuers not to have to make a full context switch to the kernel at the same time.

**Note:** Yes, technically the inclusion of `mtx_` in the queue removes the lockfree attribute, but I think this is an accurate characterization anyway since `dequeue()` is the only method that uses `mtx_` (enqueuers signal without locking).

Comment: "It appears that boost::lockfree::queue does not provide a dequeue-like method at all" - That wouldn't make much sense, would it?  Isn't that what `consume_one()` does?

Comment: @RobertHarvey check the [description](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html#idp228006400-bb), non-blocking and "**returns** true, if one element was consumed"

Comment: @ratchetfreak: It also says "if pop operation is successful, object will be copied to ret"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think `consume_one()` is like `dequeue()` - the latter is never supposed to fail, whereas the former can return false.

Comment: Then I think you need to be clear that you require the method signature *to be exactly the same.*  It would be easy enough to wrap `consume_one()` to get the `dequeue()` method you want, I think.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmm, not necessarily. I don't mind using a `Functor`-like method at all, if it's necessary, so long as the functor _always_ gets called. If you see a way, then I would appreciate it if you posted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the consume_one implementation is very likely just `T t; if(pop(t)){functor(t);return true;}return false;`

Comment: It appears the OP is looking for a non-blocking (and non-syscall) enqueue, and a blocking (sleep until done) dequeue. Perhaps putting words like "hybrid" or "semi-blocking" will help  online search. As the dequeue part must involve a syscall in the case of empty, use of conditional variable seems certain. This also means the "syscall-free enqueue" requirement must be abandoned, instead making it "non-sleeping". (Correct me if my understanding is wrong.)

Comment: @rwong That is correct. However, as my `yield` solution suggests it's entirely possible to have enqueue be block-free. I'm fairly sure that `yield` won't be ignored, even if it is just a 'hint'. In any case, if you can show there's no other way around the serialization in the dequeue, I'd appreciate a post. I've incorporated your comments into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try_lock for signaling the cond_ when enqueueing. This will have a race condition that can be circumvented by making the wait timed.

The idea is that if the try_lock fails then either another enqueuer is also trying to wake the dequeuers so we might as well let him do the work or the dequeuer is trying to wait and he may or may not have check the condition yet. If he hasn't then fine he'll see the queue isn't empty and release and try again, if he has checked then he'll check again after the timeout expires.

Comment: The problem isn't that the condition variable approach is slow when the queue is near-empty, the slowdown (compared to `this_thread::yield` mentioned in my question) occurs when dequeuers are contending over a queue that's filled with items already.

Comment: @VF1 if there are items in the queue then they shouldn't even be touching the lock (or thread::yield).

Comment: Yeah, I realized that just after I couldn't edit my comment; good point. I'm still not seeing what the `try_lock` does that `cond_.signal()` doesn't, though.

Comment: @VF1 it lets the enqueuer skip signaling if the lock is already held at the danger of a missed signal for a dequeuer.